# cmd.exe count files based on extension and creation time

Tags: sorting, cmd, counting

This problem has probably been solved a few times but I couldn't find it.
I would like to count a specific type of files in a drive and sort them based on their creation date.
Basically I want to know how many .RAW files I create every year.
The files are in multiple folders on the drive in question.

I have tired to play arond with:
dir /a:-d /s /b "H:" | find /c /v ".RAW"
it counts something, but I cant figure out how to get the creation time as well.

any ideas ?
All the best
Morten

Comment: `it counts something,` - yes the files that don't have `.RAW` in their name (`/v`*excludes* lines containing the following string. And it's case sensitive. To change, use `/i`). To count files with extension `.RAW` (`.Raw`, `raw` etc.): `dir /a:-d /s /b "H:\*.raw"`, to count them, `...|find /v /c ""` (count lines that are not empty. The `dir` command before already lists only `.rar` files (to be honest: on some systems `.rar*`, if short names are enabled)

Comment: As for the creation time, you need a command (instead of `dir`) that can filter by date (xcopy, robocopy, forfiles)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get the assistance of PowerShell:

```bash
%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -Command "$RAWfiles = Get-ChildItem -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -File -Filter '*.RAW' -Path 'H:\' -Recurse | Where-Object {($_.CreationTime).Year -Eq (Get-Date).Year}; $Listing = ForEach ($File In $RAWfiles) {New-Object PSObject -Property @{FileName = $File.FullName; Created = $File.CreationTime.ToString('yyy-MM-dd')}}; $Listing | Sort-Object -Property CreationTime | Format-Table FileName, Created -HideTableHeaders; Write-Host 'Total File(s):' $RAWfiles.Count"
```

The above example is designed only to output files created this year. If you run it next year, it will output the files created in that year instead. If this does not achieve your overall intention, and as this is not a code writing service, I will leave any modifications to you.

Comment: Please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), and consider an action based on it's content.

Comment: Dear Compo, I was not aware that my comment had been deleted. Your answer was great, and made me aware that perhaps what I need is bit more complicated than I thought. So I will try to figure that out. As you say this is not a code writing service, so I will try to modify your solution. Thank you very much for your help. Unfortunately I Cant upvote your solution since I rightfully have no credit

Comment: I think that you misunderstand, or perhaps it is me. But stackoverflow tells me that I need reputation points to mark your answer.